# telnet to azure vm port from outside

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, telnet, azure-virtual-machine

I want to telnet virtual machine on port 1234. I have server.exe running on vm which listens to port 1234.

When I run telnet within virtual machine cmd "telnet 127.0.0.1 1234" response is

> "ok"

However when I run telnet from outside using "telnet publicIP 1234" response is

> Connecting To publicIP...Could not open connection to the host, on
>   port 1234: Connect failed

I have added endpoints in azure portal and tried switching off the firewall from both virtual machine and my local machine.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

1. Make sure that your `server.exe` listens also the VM network adapter, but not only on 127.0.0.1
2. Make sure that your `ISP`( Internet Provider) does not block outgoing ports - **very** common issue.

To avoid (2) change the **public** port for the VM Endpoint to 80 and try with `telnet publicIP 80`

To make sure you comply with (1), while on the VM try `telnet **localIP** 1234`